# Mixin based mongoengine documents with class decorators instead of using multiple inheritance

Tags: python, mongoengine, python-decorators

Let's assume that I use Mongoengine to create Documents like this one:

```
class Tag(Document):
    name = fields.StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    user = fields.ReferenceField('User')
    created = fields.DateTimeField()
    updated = fields.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

`created` and `updated` are fields that are frequently used along other models and I want to separate the code for datetime related stuff into a "mixin". Using multiple inheritance is one solution:

```
class Tag(Timestampable, Document):
    name = fields.StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    user = fields.ReferenceField('User')

class Timestampable()
    created = fields.DateTimeField()
    updated = fields.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Although this works, [multiple inheritance in Python has its serious downsides](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/). Therefore we need another solution. Class decorators came into my mind:

```
@Timestampable
class Tag(Document):
    name = fields.StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    user = fields.ReferenceField('User')

def Timestampable(cls)
    cls.created = fields.DateTimeField()
    cls.updated = fields.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    return cls
```

That's cool, because i don't need to bother with any `super` calls.

**It does not work though. Both `DateTimeField`s are not created when referencing the `Tag` class.**

Is there any solution to my problem?

### Appendix

To properly understand the need for this, here is the complete mixin code for the Timestampable decorator:

```
def Timestampable(cls):
    cls.created = model_fields.DateTimeField()
    cls.updated = model_fields.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    cls_save = cls.save
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if not self.id:
            self.created = now
        self.updated = now
        return cls_save(self, *args, **kwargs)
    cls.save = save

    return cls
```